# Not able to get expected response in rest service

Tags: java, rest

I am calling a  url link which will redirect to  random url page.I  am getting response  as below when i hit through curl

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/html" -H  -L "Content-Type: application/html" -X GET http://www.randomwebsite.com/cgi-bin/random.pl


HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 25 May 2015 13:22:36 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Location: http://www.straightdope.com
ngpass_ngall: 1
Content-Length: 211
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 localhost.localdomain

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://www.straightdope.com">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

But when i  do through jersey client i  am not able to see the html document response  I get below response

```
GET http://www.randomwebsite.com/cgi-bin/random.pl returned a response status of 302 Found
private void getFtoCResponse() {
        try {

            Client client = Client.create();
            client.setFollowRedirects(false);
            WebResource webResource2 = client.resource("http://www.randomwebsite.com/cgi-bin/random.pl");


            ClientResponse response2 = webResource2.accept("text/html").get(ClientResponse.class);
            //response2.g


            System.out.println(response2);


            //InputStream stream=   response2.getEntityInputStream();
            //String myString = IOUtils.toString(stream, "UTF-8");
        //  System.out.println(myString);

            String output2 = response2.getEntity(String.class);
            System.out.println("\n============getFtoCResponse============");
            System.out.println(output2);



        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```